# Allow loading of my own website into iframe

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, firefox, iframe

There are any way to disable this security validation:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/page/1 does not permit framing.
```

This is occuring because I am trying add my own url into a iframe on my app.

I tried do something like this in the page that responds in the url above:

```
<% response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM: localhost"); %>
<% response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW"); %>
<% response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAME-ORIGIN"); %>
```

None of them worked!

Comment: nope, both are running in the same server @RobSedgwick

Answer (score 1):

The follow code solved my question:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/page/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView load(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response) {
response.setHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN");

Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
...
return new ModelAndView("page", parameters);
```

}